# DNS points to wrong website IIS7

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, bindings

I have 2 websites. The old one, website.co.uk, and the new one, **www**.website.co.uk
However the DNS seems to have different bindings.
http://website.co.uk loads a completely different site to http://**www**.website.co.uk

When a user types in either http://website.co.uk or http://**www**.website.co.uk I want the DNS to resolve and redirect the user to the new site (**www**.website.co.uk)

How can this be done?
I am using IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps to solve this.

**Step 1: Reconfigure DNS**
Your DNS will need to have two A records. One for `website.co.uk` and a second one for `www.website.co.uk`. Since you want them going to the same spot, these two records need to have the same IP address. It sounds like they currently don't. This needs to be fixed, either with your hosting service, or with whomever is hosting the DNS for your domain.

**Step 2: Configure redirection**
This is an IIS setting, and there are a couple of ways of accomplishing this. One way is to use a name-based bind for `website.co.uk` and put an app there that all it does is do an HTTP redirect for the equivalent URL at `wwww.website.co.uk`. IIS also has a 'rewrite' module which can do much the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You change it by reconfiguring the DNS to point to the same IP.